# Having trouble with pgfSweave and tikzDevice

Tags: r, sweave

On [Ben Bolker's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8281897/707145) advice I started using `pgfSweave` and `tikzDevice`. I'm struggling with getting `R` graphs into LaTeX.

This is my code for `pgfSweave Rnw` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\title{Minimal pgfSweave Example}
\author{Cameron Bracken}

\begin{document}

<<setup,echo=F>>=
setCacheDir("cache")
options(keep.space=TRUE)
@


\maketitle
This example is identical to that in the Sweave manual and is intended to
introduce pgfSweave and highlight the basic differences. Please refer to
the pgfSweave vignette for more usage instructions.
We embed parts of the examples from the \texttt{kruskal.test} help page
into a \LaTeX{} document:

<<data,cache=T,tidy=T>>=
# hey, a comment
data(airquality)
print(kruskal.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality )) # and another
@

\noindent which shows that the location parameter of the Ozone distribution varies
significantly from month to month. Finally we include a boxplot of the data:

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  %notice the new options
  {\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=
    {\includegraphics[width=3in]{#1}}}

    <<boxplot, echo=T, fig=T, width=3, height=3, tikz=T, external=T, highlight=T>>=
      boxplot(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality,
        main='Ozone distribution',xlab='Month',ylab='Concentration')
     @
   }% this brace ends the effect of `include external'
  \caption{This is from pgfSweave. Text is typset by \LaTeX\ and so matches the
           font of the document.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which  produces

[image: pgfSweave output]

and the `tikzDevice Rnw` code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[nogin]{Sweave}

\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
library(tikzDevice)
@

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering

  <<inline, echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
  tikz(console=TRUE, width=5, height=5)
  x <- rnorm (100)
  plot(x)
  dummy <- dev.off()
  @

  \caption{caption}
  \label{fig:inline}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: tikzDevice output]

My question is: What am I missing? Both `Rnw` codes do not produce `R` graphs in `pdf` to include in a LaTeX document. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I removed the thanks. This is just the style here. Any thanks is best expressed as voting for answers that help you.

Comment: I don't think you can indent the `<<...>>` and `@` lines.  Does it work if you remove the indentation from those lines?

Comment: @Aaron: You are absolutely right. Both codes are working after removing the indentation. Would you mind to include your comment as answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In both cases, the Sweave chunks should not be indented.

When the Sweave driver (a part of R) parses the input file, it recognizes as chunks of R code blocks that begin with a `<<` at the start of a line, and end with a `@`. Because your `<<` is not at the start of a line, those blocks are never run as R code, and no plots are produced.